# How to align button's title to right using react-native-elements?

Tags: react-native, button, react-native-elements

I am using react-native-elements to add button in my app, but i am unable to align the text inside the button to right.

I tried titleStyle property with alignText:'right' but with no success

```
<Button title={'Hello World'} titleStyle={{ textAlign:'right' }} />
```

I wanted the button title to align to the right but it just stays in the center.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can easily do this by adding justifyContent 'flex-end' to React Native Elements Button buttonStyle props

```
<Button
  title="My Button"
  type="clear"
  buttonStyle={{ justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for saving my time!

Answer (score 2):

Passing your own `Text` as children into `Button` would solve your problems.
But in React-native you can't call a `Text` as children into `Button`. Because "The Title props of a `Button` must be a string".

So Instead of using `Button` you can use `TouchableOpacity`.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {console.log('button press')}}>
   <Text style={{textAlign:'right'}}>Hello World</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Or you can create a Button Component.
like this.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const Button = ({ onPress, children }) => {
  const { buttonStyle, textStyle } = styles;
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={buttonStyle}>
      <Text style={textStyle}>
        {children}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

export default Button;

const styles = {
  textStyle: {
    textAlign: 'right',
    color: '#336633',
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: '600',
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingBottom: 10
  },
  buttonStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#336633',
    paddingTop: 4,
    paddingBottom: 4,
    paddingRight: 25,
    paddingLeft: 25,
    marginTop: 10,
    marginLeft: 15,
    marginRight:15,
    width: 380
  }
};
```